# Autofac, ASP.NET MVC 3 httpRequest scope and AutoMapper: No scope with a Tag matching 'httpRequest' is visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, autofac

When I use a web type registered with autofac from an automapper mapping, I get this error:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'httpRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being reqested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

When another type is resolved in the mapping it works.
When a web type is resolved from the controller it works.

Why doesnt web (or any other httprequest scoped?) types get successfully resolved in my mapping?

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AssignableTo<Profile>()
            .As<Profile>()
            ;
        builder.Register(c => Mapper.Engine)
            .As<IMappingEngine>();
        builder.RegisterType<AnotherType>()
            .As<IAnotherType>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        var profiles = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>();
        Mapper.Initialize(c => profiles.ToList().ForEach(c.AddProfile));

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mapper;
    private readonly Func<HttpContextBase> _httpContext;

    public HomeController(IMappingEngine mapper, Func<HttpContextBase> httpContext)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var test = _httpContext.Invoke();
        return View(_mapper.Map<Model, ViewModel>(new Model()));
    }

}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly Func<HttpContextBase> _httpContext;
    private readonly Func<IAnotherType> _anotherType;

    public MyProfile(Func<HttpContextBase> httpContext, Func<IAnotherType> anotherType)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _anotherType = anotherType;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Url, o => o.ResolveUsing(s =>
                                                    {
                                                        var test = _anotherType.Invoke().GetAValue();
                                                        return _httpContext.Invoke().Request.Url;
                                                    }))
            ;
    }
}

public interface IAnotherType
{
    string GetAValue();
}

public class AnotherType : IAnotherType
{
    public string GetAValue() { return "a value"; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
}
```

**EDIT**: Its easy to create an empty MVC project, paste the code and try it out and see for yourself.

**EDIT**: Removed the ConstructServicesUsing call because its not required by the example. No services are resolved through AutoMapper in the example.

Answer (score 2):

@rene_r above is on the right track; adapting his answer:

```
c.ConstructServicesUsing(t => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(t))
```

Still might not compile but should get you close.

The requirement is that the call to `DependencyResolver.Current` is deferred until the service is requested (not kept as the value returned by `Current` when the mapper was initialised.)

Comment: Removed the call completely because however its made it doesnt make a difference, and I dont think it really matters because no services are resolved through automapper in the example.

Comment: `var profiles = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>();` won't work - `MyProfile` depends on `HttpContext` which is a per-request type (`Func` doesn't alter this).

Comment: Hmm, I followed an example somewhere on how to pass dependencies to mappings, maybe obviously that doesnt work in this case. How would you suggest I provide dependencies for my mappings if not this way?

Comment: Where you able to get this working? I'm having similar problems

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DependencyResolver.Current.Resolve instead of container.Resolve in

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
                {                               
                   c.ConstructServicesUsing(DependencyResolver.Current);
                   profiles.ToList().ForEach(c.AddProfile);
                 });
```

Comment: That doesnt even compile, but changing it to          c.ConstructServicesUsing(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService);
it compiles, but its still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and it turned out to be a bad setup in my bootstrapper function. The following autofac setup did it for me.

```
builder.Register(c => new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.Mappers))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => Mapper.Engine)
    .As<IMappingEngine>()
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<TypeMapFactory>()
    .As<ITypeMapFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

I did not have to specify resolver in the Mapper.Initialize() function. Just called

```
Mapper.Initialize(x => 
            {
                x.AddProfile<DomainToDTOMappingProfile>(); 
            });
```

after the bootstrapped and it works fine for me.